# Kendo UI DataSource/Grid Change Client Filter Parameters

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, filtering, kendo-datasource

When using the Kendo UI Grid I can manipulate requests being sent to the server using the `parameterMap` in the `transport` option if I set the dataSource to use `serverPaging`, `serverFiltering`, and/or `serverSorting`. Specifically I am looking for certain fields in the filter of a read request and I am changing the name of the field being filtered.

When doing all of my filtering, sorting, and paging client-side the `transport` options, including `parameterMap` no longer apply. Is there some other way that I can modify filter requests for client-side filtering?

I am using jQuery version 2017.2.621.

---

EDIT to include requested code. This is for changing the fields on server filtering/sorting. Need to accomplish this with client-side.

```
var dataSourceGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "my_line_id",
                fields: modelFields
            },
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        },
        pageSize: 15,
        serverPaging: false,
        serverFiltering: false,
        serverSorting: false,
        transport: {
            create: {
                url: "./grid.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {action: 'read', my_id: my_id},
                dataType: "json"
            },
            read: {
                url: "./grid.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {action: 'read', my_id: my_id},
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "./grid.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {action: 'update', my_id: my_id},
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                if (type === "read" && data.filter) {
                    $.each(data.filter.filters, function (i, v) {
                        if (v.field === 'field_1') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_1';
                        }
                        if (v.field === 'field_2') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_2';
                        }
                        if (v.field === 'field_3') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_3';
                        }
                        if (v.field === 'field_4') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_4';
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (type === "read" && data.sort) {
                    $.each(data.sort, function (i, v) {
                        if (v.field === 'field_1') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_1';
                        }
                        if (v.field === 'field_2') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_2';
                        }
                        if (v.field === 'field_3') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_3';
                        }
                        if (v.field === 'field_4') {
                            v.field = 'new_field_4';
                        }
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show the code that is changing the filter ?

Comment: Updated the question to include code snippet.